# Convert from object {object[]} to List<int>

Tags: c#

I need to convert from

```
object {object[]}
```

to

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int>
```

Inside each element in the object array there is a `object {int}` element.
I got this structure from a COM dll.

I was wondering how is the easiest way to do that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming it's how it is shown in the debugger

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
List<int> intList = objectArray.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: I think `Cast<int>` is more appropriate because _"Inside **each** element ..."_. The additional type check should be redundant.

Comment: Before that I need to cast from object to object[]

Comment: Ok, that was simple. `object[] idArray = (object[])idObject;`

Comment: And I decided to use the casting suggested by @TimSchmelter. `            List<int> idList = idArray.Cast<int>().ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Int> ObjToList(object[] objects)
{
    List<int> intList = new list<int>();
    foreach (object o in objects)
    {
        intList.Add((int)o);
    }
    return intList;
}
```

be very sure that all your objects in the array are of type int to avoid problems

Answer (score 1):

My attempt on this converts the `object` array into a `int` array and checks if there are no `null` entries in the original object array. This is how I go on converting my object array to a `List<int>`:

```
using System.Linq;

//Your object array depends on your data source. I am taking an example of json data
object[] myObjectArray= jsonData["data"]; 

int[] myIntegerArray= myObjectArray.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();

List<int> myIntegerList= myIntegerArray.ToList();
```